# Extract substring from a python string

Tags: python

I want to extract the string before the 9 digit number below:

`tmp = place1_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif`

The output should be `place1`

I could do this:
`tmp.split('_')[0]` but I also want the solution to work for:

`tmp = place1_place2_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif` where the result would be:
`place1_place2`

You can assume that the number will also be 9 digits long

Comment: Try Python regular rexpressions: `m = re.search("\d{9}", tmp); print(m.group())`

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions at all? Check out `re.search()`, a regular expression for what you need would look like `'.+(?=_\d{9}_)'`, that is: one or more characters before an underscore before 9 digits (followed by an underscore); check sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to design and test regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expressions and the lookahead feature of regex, this is a simple solution:

```
tmp = "place1_place2_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif"
m = re.search(r'.+(?=_\d{9}_)', tmp)
print(m.group())
```

Result:

```
place1_place2
```

Note that the `\d{9}` bit matches exactly 9 digits. And the bit of the regex that is in `(?= ... )` is a lookahead, which means it is not part of the actual match, but it only matches if that follows the match.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we can phrase your problem as wanting the substring up to, but not including the underscore which is followed by all numbers, we can try:

```py
tmp = "place1_place2_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif"
m = re.search(r'^([^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*)_\d+_', tmp)
print(m.group(1))  # place1_place2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

places = (
    "place1_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif",
    "place1_place2_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif",
)
pattern = re.compile("(place\d+(?:_place\d+)*)_\d{9}")
for p in places:
    matched = pattern.match(p)
    if matched:
        print(matched.group(1))
```

prints:

> place1

> place1_place2

The regex works like this (adjust as needed, e.g., for less than 9 digits or a variable number of digits):

- `(` starts a capture
- `place\d+` matches "places plus 1 to many digits"
- `(?:` starts a group, but does not capture it (no need to capture)
- `_place\d+` matches more "places"
- `)` closes the group
- `*` means zero or many times the previous group
- `)` closes the capture
- `\d{9}` matches 9 digits

The result is in the first (and only) capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution without regex (unoptimized!):

```
def extract(s):
    result = ''
    for x in s.split('_'):
        try: x = int(x)
        except: pass
        if isinstance(x, int) and len(str(x)) == 9:
            return result[:-1]
        else:
            result += x + '_'

tmp = 'place1_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif'
tmp2 = 'place1_place2_128017000_gw_cl_mask.tif'

print(extract(tmp))   # place1
print(extract(tmp2))  # place1_place2
```